# Delay start date on the other offer -- how to if possible

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, new-job, recruitment

I have 2 job offers – one's already been made, the other is on the way. 
I like them both.

I'll take the one that's been already offered, say `job-1`. call the other `job-2`.

I'll take `job-1` because it's

- a very good contract
- been elaborating progressively for a while (government contract). Saying no to it (not that I'm considering to do so) wouldn't only be unprofessional, would also be shutting all the doors, for good, not just to similar roles, but to the major agency getting me hired for this project

`job-2` is a permanent role. I started talking to them more recently. 
They didn't ask and i didn't tell about "any other prospects, possible other offers, timeline on these.."
It's a company that i see myself in the long run. but not at the cost of giving up on `job-1`. 
so - what I want is to defer `job-2` for
6 months from now-- till I'll have finished `job-1`.

Is this any doable?

Every way i look, this "feels" too much to ask. I wouldn't like it a tiny bit if I were the company of `job-2`.

Is it fair even to mention this possibility to `job-2`?

I'm looking for opinion on how to go about it. i like `job-2` also - don't wanna give up on it just like that.

Comment: Why not tell job-2 the truth?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul how? not sounding like 'i'm in demand, gotta defer you guys'

Comment: Why do you think that's a bad image though? You clearly value the job 1 first, so tell the job 2 that you will love to join them, but first must finish the job 1 that you've already accepted, but will finish in two months.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul 6 months not 2. 2  months is merely  project - wouldn't mind saying that. 6 months is different

Comment: Sorry, that was typo in my mind it was six months. I still don't understand why do you think this is a bad solution?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul maybe not. might be reasonable to ask&leave a door open for 6 months after. after all, i'm doing this for i like them

Comment: What you have to ask is can Job-2 find a better candidate than you in that 6 months... Answer is most likely yes so you loose

Comment: @SolarMike nope - that's their business "can they find a better candidate". this is not to rule out the option for 6 months later which, i now think, is fair to consider. there're always other/better options. your angle sounds too manipulative.

Comment: You specifically asked for an opinion - i gave you one: live with it.

Answer (score 2):

> every way i look, this "feels" too much to ask.

It is a lot to ask. But if you don't ask, you won't know.

If you do ask, be prepared with a response, if the answer is "No. We won't wait that long."

> i'm looking for opinion on how to go about it.

Something like "I'd love to accept your offer. And I could see myself in this company for a long time. But I am already committed to a contract job for the next 6 months. Could I start once my contract ends?"

Then, listen to the reply and proceed accordingly.